# Generalized JSON parser for Swift

Tags: ios, json

In our iOS project, we are using SwiftyJSON and ObjectMapper to parse JSON responses and store them in models. However, for the models, we have to manually specify the mapping. eg; if I have a model class called User, which has name and age as properties, then while parsing, I have to specify the following in the User class:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
        name <- map["Name"]
        age <- map["Age"]
    }
```

Doing the same for all models is tedious and time consuming. Isn't there an approach to generalize the parsing? Like I pass any JSON to a function and specify the model, and the function should return me the model object with the parsed values, if they're available. I don't want to write a separate mapping for each model.

Comment: lol you want shortcut of a shortcut!

Comment: It'll be very helpful for projects which have large number of models. Plus I suppose libraries like Gson in Android are already doing the same thing.

Comment: This is a very valid question @StudentX , and you can use http://www.json4swift.com to create mappable objects for objectmapper from your json sample.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection), a Swift 3 library which does what you are looking for.

Update:

Swift 4 (now in Beta) seems to be bringing some changes which are relevant to this question.

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
  var str: String
  var num: Int
}

let myStruct = MyStruct(str: "test", num:5)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try encoder.encode(myStruct)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)

print(json) // prints {"str": "test", "num": 5}

// Also decoding

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decoded = try decoder.decode(MyStruct.self, from: jsonData)

// decoded is a structure of type MyStruct

print(decoded.str) // test
```

Comment: <shameless plug>Using this will make working with Codable in Swift 4 even easier: https://github.com/evermeer/Stuff#codable </shameless plug>